# Million mesh programmatically?

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-4

I have a flat surface drawn with a single fullscreen `GL_QUAD`.

I want to deform this surface at each point specified by my `GL_Texture2D`, preferably through some kind of shader.

In my mind, black could correspond to flat and white could correspond to a hill.

I want to have about 4 million points on my terrain and update them at each step in my program.

How would I use a geometry shader to do this? Is a shader able to generate new veritices?

Comment: Can you restructure your question so that it's not answerable with a simple "yes" or "no"?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to any programming language other than GLSL; remove the c++ tag.

Comment: Are you using OpenGL 4.0 or higher? If you are, then it sounds like you should be using tessellation shaders (not a geometry shader) to do what you want.

Comment: I don't see why you would need a geometry shader. Just use a vertex shader as @jozxyqk suggested. If you really want to modify the vertex coordinates at each step, i.e. save the calculations done in the vertex shader, have a look at transform feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to generate a large triangle strip grid, upload it to a VBO and draw it, using the vertex shader to alter just the up coordinate. The vertex shader can also generate normals from the heightmap (or supply a normal map), which then get passed to the fragment shader for lighting.

To avoid storing a huge amount of data for the vertices, use glVertexID to generate the vertex positions from scratch in the vertex shader. Don't bind any buffers, simply call glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, lots).

As GuyRT mentioned, a tessellation shader would be good too and allow you to vary the tessellation detail based on the camera's distance to the mesh. This would be more work though.